# Rendering Error Cardview android studio 3.1 and appCompact Theme Error

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I get the problem within android studio regarding cardview rendering error and appCompact Theme Error. here is the screenshot and the gradle code

[Android Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LppCZ.png)

[App Theme error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it373.png)

[I have tried this solution and still doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw324.png)

----Here is the gradle code----

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {  
    compileSdkVersion 27  
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId "com.example.shirazikudou.firebase4"  
        minSdkVersion 23  
        targetSdkVersion 27  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"    
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-      android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}  

dependencies {  
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-      core:2.2.2', {  
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-    annotations'  
    })  
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-    layout:1.1.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'  
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:3.0.2'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'  
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'  
}  

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try replace `api` to `implementation` in your `'com.androud.support:appcompat'`

Comment: @KopiBryant still the same sir

Comment: `cardView` as well. Replace yours to mine `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: @KopiBryant didn't work sir

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @KopiBryant the application loosing the app Theme and cardview rendering error sir